# How do I get one of the coordinates of rotation in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to a cube do not rotate more than 60 degrees so it dosn't rotate to more
I tried to use this

```
if(gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().rotation.x >= 60 || gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().rotation.x <= -60 || gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().rotation.z >= 60 || gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().rotation.z <= -60)
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().rotation = new Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```

to check the rotation. 
It didn't work so I print what rotation is getting in the x coordinate

and it said cordinates like:
5.98324, 7.39482, -1.983495

and I was just moving the x position not the rotation and It change it.

So how do I get the x rotation that it sais in the component transform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way you approached is fine but not suitable for the scenario. `Euler Angles` should be handled in order to control the Transformation.

simple understanding be like:

```
// declare your cube rotation 
float moveSpeed = 5f // speed in which cube rotates
float rotatecube = moveSpeed* Time.deltaTime* 10;

//Your condition be like
 if(transform.eulerAngles.z < (.....declare the requirement.....))
  transform.Rotate(vector3.forward * rotateCube);
```

If you still face any issue related to angles `console.log()` is the better way for self understandings.
Hope it clarifies..

Answer (score 2):

You are interested in the **euler angles** of the rotation, not the **quaternion components** of the rotation. You should start by referring to [`transform.eulerAngles.x`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) instead of  `transform.rotation.x` or `transform.eulerAngles.z` instead of `transform.rotation.z`.

By the way, it's best to call `GetComponent` as few times as you can get away with as it's an expensive operation. You should rather call it once and assign the result to a variable such as this:

```
Transform cubeTransform = gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>(); 
if(cubeTransform.eulerAngles.x ...)
{
   ...
}
```

Additionally, you don't even need to use `GetComponent` to access the `transform` of the `gameObject` the script is attached to. Instead, you can just use `transform`, e.g.:

```
if (   transform.eulerAngles.x >= 60 || transform.eulerAngles.x <= -60 
    || transform.eulerAngles.z >= 60 || transform.eulerAngles.z <= -60)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
    }
```

Comment: thanks I didn't know that i needed to refer as that

Answer (score -1):

Basicaly, you want to make limit of rotation of any axis - x,y, or z.

if yes, then here is the solution :

Program:
Rotating A cube not more that 60 degree in x and z only.

var rotValue += Time.deltaTime;
Cube.transform.rotaion = Quaternion.Eular(Mathf.Clamp(rotaValue,0,60), 0, Mathf.Clamp(rotaValue,0,60));

you can use Mathf.clamp for Clamping any Float value Between min and max.
hope, problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

Skip all the above comments. I found a way to get the exact rotation values as in INSPECTOR. I am showing for angle **(x)**. The code is as follows:

```
 public Transform GameObject;
 
 void Update()
 {
     float Rotation;
     if(GameObject.eulerAngles.x <= 180f)
     {
         Rotation = GameObject.eulerAngles.x;
     }
     else
     {
         Rotation = GameObject.eulerAngles.x - 360f;
     }
 }
```

Comment: No, this often will not give you the rotation values in the inspector.